# How to automate root device volume's tagging using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am not able to [tag](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html) the [root device volume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html) attached to [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) using [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/)'s [block device mapping](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html) because [tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html) are not propagated to Amazon [EBS](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) volumes that are created from [block device mappings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html). Can [root device volume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/RootDeviceStorage.html)'s [tagging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html) be *automated* using [Cloudformation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) in any way? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### CloudFormation

This has just shipped in CloudFormation settable via the property

PropagateTagsToVolumeOnCreation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-propagatetagstovolumeoncreation

### User Data

This is possible to do using [UserData](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-user-data-retrieval) - if you are running a linux host with cloudinit and the [awscli installed](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html), it's possible to run the following in your [UserData](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-user-data-retrieval) script to tag all the volumes associate with an Instance

```
"VOLUME_IDS=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --output text --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --query 'Volumes[].VolumeId')",
"aws ec2 create-tags --resources ${VOLUME_IDS} --tags Key=my,Value=tag"
```

- [retrieves current instance id](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html)
- [uses the instance id as filter in describe volumes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volumes.html)
- [jmespath query to returns just the volume ids](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)
- [volume ids passed to create tags with the tag/s you wish to add](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html)

ensure that when you launch your EC2 Instance it has an Instance IAM Policy that enables it to create tags and describe volumes

```js
"PolicyDocument": {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumes"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

## CloudWatch Events
Another way to automate this is via CloudWatch Events, set up an Events rule listening for and EC2 State Change, then tag The volumes in a Lambda function, I've included a couple of CloudFormation snippets below

```
LambdaEC2CopyTagsToEBS:
  Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: 2012-10-17
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
              - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
    Policies:
      - PolicyName: LambdaEC2CopyTagsToEBS
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: 2012-10-17
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - ec2:DescribeInstances
                - ec2:CreateTags
              Resource: '*'

            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - logs:CreateLogGroup
                - logs:CreateLogStream
                - logs:PutLogEvents
              Resource: '*'

LambdaEC2CopyTagsToEBSEvent:
  Type: AWS::Events::Rule
  Properties:
    Description: Invokes CopyInstanceTagsToEBSVolumes when an Instance starts running
    EventPattern:
      source:
        - aws.ec2
      detail-type:
        - EC2 Instance State-change Notification
      detail:
        state:
          - running
    State: ENABLED
    Targets:
      - Arn: !GetAtt CopyInstanceTagsToEBSVolumes.Arn
        Id: !Ref CopyInstanceTagsToEBSVolumes

CopyInstanceTagsToEBSVolumes:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    Description: Copies Tags from and EC2 to all its EBS Volumes
    Code:
      ZipFile: |
        import boto3
        ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')


        def get_volume_ids(instance):
            for device in instance.get('BlockDeviceMappings', []):
                yield device.get('Ebs', {}).get('VolumeId')


        def handler(event, context):
            state, instance_id = event['detail']['state'], event['detail']['instance-id']
            if state == 'running':
                instance = ec2.describe_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])
                instance = instance['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]
                volume_ids = get_volume_ids(instance)
                tags = [tag for tag in instance['Tags'] if not tag['Key'].startswith('aws:')]
                ec2.create_tags(Resources=list(volume_ids),
                                Tags=tags
                                )

    Handler: index.handler
    Role: !GetAtt LambdaEC2CopyTagsToEBS.Arn
    Runtime: python3.6
    Timeout: 5


EventsInvokeCopyInstanceTagsToEBSVolumes:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
    FunctionName: !Ref CopyInstanceTagsToEBSVolumes
    Principal: events.amazonaws.com
    SourceArn: !GetAtt LambdaEC2CopyTagsToEBSEvent.Arn
```